# Building a MS Teams app in AWS - using azure as third party IdP

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-active-directory, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to build a MS Teams app that will sign users in with their MS credentials. Using a cognito user pool with the hosted UI, I was able to set this up using azure AD as an IdP.

The problem with this approach is that the tokens returned from the IdP are replaced by cognito's own tokens, which means calls to the microsoft graph api are unauthorized.

There is a really handy feature for this specific use case https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cognito-user-pool-tokens-issued-by-idp where you can map the IdP access token to the user object as a custom attribute.

The problem here is that the token received from azure is over the 2,048 max char limit for custom string attributes, so it errors.

I'm not the most advanced/experienced software engineer at the moment, and I'm really struggling now to think of the next move going forward as I feel like I'm going to make the wrong choice and end up wasting more time.

Ideally I wouldn't need to host anything myself on Azure, but really want users to be able to login with their MS credentials in my app.

I have managed to use MSAL on the frontend side of my app, which authenticates with azure directly, and returns the tokens back to the FE, but then I have the issue of not having any cognito users to authenticate against for my API hosted in AWS

Is this an issue? Could I just have a custom lambda authorizer that validates credentials with azure?
Is there a better route to solve this problem?

Would really appreciate any replies as I'm starting to lose the drive to work on this project, and that's depressing because I was so pumped before running into this issue.

Comment: A) Greatly structured and clear question. B) don't lose drive! there's a solution to every problem :) C) the main question here is why are you using Cognito? Is it just to connect to Azure as an IdP? Is it to provide MSFT AD authentication for your AWS API Gateway? Would authenticating the users for your API Gateway without Cognito but with the MSAL token be an option for you? The answer will determine the right solution to this problem.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I did just have an idea before I saw this! 
I'm thinking of getting rid of cognito completely, and using MSAL to retrieve tokens from azure on the FE.
After this, I can send these tokens with requests to my backend where a custom authorizer can run against these tokens.
I can then decode the id_token and use the email form that to perform a lookup against a user Dynamo table where I could handle setting things like user tier between free, premium, etc.
The authorizer could then use this information to determine the policy that is returned.

Comment: I think decoupling the identity from the user permissions like this would help me, and I think~ this flow sounds like it could work, but I'm going to get a PoC going before I get too excited haha :)

Thank you again for the reply! Reading through I think we came to the same conclusion so that fills me with a bit of hope!

Comment: Correct yes, I don’t think you really need Cognito here. Just make sure you properly validate the access token and the ID token based on issuer (iss), audience (aud) and expiry (exp) at the very least. Give me a shout if you need any help with the PoC  :) you’re on the right track.

Comment: Feel free to self answer your question after your POC is up and running.